# How can i use For Loop initialize value start depend by the condition for(k = (Char[i] == ' '? i - 1 : i ); j<k ; j++, k--)

Tags: c

[image]

```
for(k = (Char[i] ==' '? i-1 :i);j<k ; j++,k--)
```

For loop k initialize value assign if `char[i] = ' '` get space then k value is assign `i - 1`, Otherwise k value is start `k = i` value, my first condition is work if char of array get space, But when not get space k value is not assign  `k = i` value. How can I solve this?

Always my first condition works: `k = i-1`,

Comment: Reading through [this blog post](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert may help you figure out where your code's behavior is diverging from your expectations.

Comment: `' '?` is always true (non-zero.)

Comment: If you want people to help you, you need to post your code *here* **as text** that others can cut-and-paste and run to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @NeilEdelman `==` had a higher precedence than `?:`.

Comment: @ThomasJager oops, right; I guess I find the spacing confusing.

Comment: What do you want it to do, exactly?

Comment: a[i] == '\0' will never be true since you check for it in the for statement on the previous line

Comment: See [Why the `gets()` function is too dangerous to be used — ever!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used) for reasons not to use `gets()` and alternatives.  And `void main()` is not best practice (though it is documented for Windows — it is non-standard otherwise; use [`int main(void)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/) if you ignore command line arguments or `int main(int argc, char **argv)` if you process command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume that you are trying to reverse each word in the string.  If so, this will work:

Add:

```
#include <string.h>
```

And change to this:

```
    for (i = j = k = 0; i <= strlen(a); i++) {
            if (a[i] == ' ' || a[i] == '\0')
            {
                    for (k = i-1 ; j < k; j++, k--) {
                            temp = a[j];
                            a[j] = a[k];
                            a[k] = temp;
                    } 
                    j = i + 1;
            }
    }
```

Your current code will exit the for loop when you hit the null character so the last word is never reversed

Comment: Yes brother my current code last word is not reverse, i want second For loop k value is initialize i - 1 when a[i] == ' ' otherwise k value is initialize i ,If k value is initialize i then last word can be reverse , so how  can i write code into for loop

Comment: Did you try this code?  If so, what exactly didn't work for you?

Comment: yes ,this code work, but i want don't use  strlen(i), for(k = (Char[i] ==' '? i-1 :i);j<k ; j++,k--) k is always initialize  k = i - 1; but i want if Char[i] =='\0 '  k is initialize k = i; so how can i write for loop   initialize  is depend by condition